# pushed off bris on shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, brit-milah

only a bris that is on time on the eighth day is done on shabbos (ch 19 mesechta shabbos), so a mohel who performs a belated bris on shabbos is mechalel shabbos, does that invalidate the bris being that it was done "illegally"?

Answer (score 1):

> Mishna Shabbat chapter 19 verse 4:
>
> מִי שֶׁהָיוּ לוֹ שְׁתֵּי תִינוֹקוֹת, אֶחָד לָמוּל אַחַר הַשַּׁבָּת
>   וְאֶחָד לָמוּל בְּשַׁבָּת, וְשָׁכַח וּמָל אֶת שֶׁל אַחַר הַשַּׁבָּת
>   בְּשַׁבָּת, חַיָּב. אֶחָד לָמוּל בְּעֶרֶב שַׁבָּת וְאֶחָד לָמוּל
>   בְּשַׁבָּת, וְשָׁכַח וּמָל אֶת שֶׁל עֶרֶב שַׁבָּת בְּשַׁבָּת, רַבִּי
>   אֱלִיעֶזֶר מְחַיֵּב חַטָּאת, וְרַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ פּוֹטֵר: [The amoraim
>   differ in the gemara as to the correct version of this Mishnah. The
>   version subscribed to by my rabbis is the essential one, viz.:] If one
>   had two children to circumcise: one, after Shabbath; the other, on
>   Shabbath, and he forgot and circumcised the first on Shabbath, and the
>   second after Shabbath, he is liable (for a sin-offering). **(If he
>   had) one to circumcise on Sabbath eve, and the other on Shabbath, and
>   he circumcised the first on Shabbath, R. Eliezer rules that he is
>   liable for a sin-offering, and R. Yehoshua exempts him.** [This is the
>   interpretation: If he forgot and circumcised the after-Shabbath child
>   on Shabbath, all hold that he is liable. For he erred in the
>   performance of a mitzvah and did not perform a mitzvah when he
>   circumcised the after-Shabbath child on Shabbath. In this, even R.
>   Yehoshua concurs. ("one to circumcise on Shabbath, and one to
>   circumcise on Sabbath eve, and he forgot and circumcised the Sabbath
>   eve child on Shabbath, R. Eliezer rules that he is liable for a
>   sin-offering":) For milah beyond its time does not override Shabbath.
>   And even though he erred in the performance of a mitzvah, being taken
>   up with the Shabbath circumcision, for which reason he erred with the
>   other — **and even though he performed a mitzvah even with the first,
>   for he was fit for circumcision, though not for circumcision
>   overriding Shabbath** — R. Eliezer holds that if one erred in the
>   performance of a mitzvah and performed a mitzvah which does not
>   override Shabbath, he is liable. ("and R. Yehoshua exempts him":) He
>   holds that if one erred in the performance of a mitzvah and performed
>   a mitzvah which does not override Shabbath, he is exempt; for he felt
>   that he was operating under the sanction of beth-din. **The halachah
>   is in accordance with R. Yehoshua**.]

I have highlighted the significant text where Rabbi Yehoshua, according to whom the halacha follows, exempts him from bringing a korban chatat because he has fulfilled a mitzvah.

Ergo, the milah is valid (unlike the other case discussed here).

Comment: Perhaps you could cite your source that we follow R' Yehoshua over R' Eliezer?

Comment: Where is your English quotation from?

Comment: @cashcow that's in a case of where it was a case of he thought "this baby" is supposed to be the one that's getting the bris but what about in a case of a single baby that was not supposed to get a bris on shabbos  (pushed off)?

Comment: The logic is that he has performed a mitzvah of Milah... see the bold quote about 6 lines up. Therefore the Milah is valid even if he shouldn't have done it on Shabbat.

Comment: The website from which I copied that is: http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Shabbat.19.4/en/The_Mishna_with_Obadiah_Bartenura_by_Rabbi_Shraga_Silverstein?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Also it appears R Eliezer and R Yehoshua only differ in whether he is liable to a Chatat, and not whether the Milah is valid.

Comment: @cashcow I quote "he is exempt; for he
felt that he was operating under the
sanction of beth-din" but in this case he doesn't have any reason to feel that he's "operating under the sanction of beth-din"

Comment: The key question is whether or not the bris is valid. It is clear from the text that, as the child is due Bris Milah on Shabbas it is a valid bris milah, even if it should not have been done on that day.